# Starting container process caused "exec: \"/tmp/run.sh\": permission denied": unknown

Tags: shell, docker, unix, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM composer:1.8.5 as build_stage

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN composer install


FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk --no-cache add \
php7 \
php7-mbstring \
php7-session \
php7-openssl \
php7-tokenizer \
php7-json \
php7-pdo \
php7-pdo_pgsql \
php7-pgsql
COPY --from=build_stage /src  /src
RUN ls -al
RUN set -x \
addgroup -g 82 -S www-data \
adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data
WORKDIR /src
RUN ls -al
RUN chmod -R 777 storage
RUN sudo chmod +x run.sh
copy ./run.sh /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/run.sh"]
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /app
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

and when I run, I kept getting

[image]

How would one go about and debug this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RUN sudo chmod +x run.sh
copy ./run.sh /tmp
```

You are copying a fresh copy from the build context without execute permission onto `/tmp/run.sh`. Try to change those command for the following.

```
RUN chmod +x run.sh
RUN cp run.sh /tmp
```

Note that sudo isn't needed because you are already as root.

Comment: Should my Dockerfile look like ? like this  : https://i.imgur.com/yyu8f7d.png

Comment: @kyo, yes, don't forget the ENTRYPOINT

Comment: oh yeah you're right. I forgot that. trying that now.

Comment: yep. It went pass that issue. now.

Comment: @codestation can you please help to solve question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126322/unknown-error-after-kill-did-not-terminate-sucessfully-signaling-init-process-c

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in this block:

```
RUN sudo chmod +x run.sh
copy ./run.sh /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/run.sh"]
```

You make run.sh executable, then overwrite it with a non-executable version. Switching the order of the two commands should fix it:

```
COPY ./run.sh /tmp
RUN chmod +x /tmp/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/run.sh"]
```

Comment: This won't work because the `WORKDIR` is on /src so the copy on `/tmp` still doesn't have execute permission.